# Version 1.2 reflection EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: swift, reflection

Following code worked fine in 1.1 and stops working at the reflection `reflect(a)` in 1.2

```
class AClass {
    var some : String = "Hans"
    var thing : Double
    init( t: Double ) {
        thing = t
    }
}

class BClass : AClass {

}

var a = BClass(t: 1.1)

var mirror = reflect(a) // FAILS
for var index=0; index<mirror.count; ++index {

}
```

Though `reflect(a).valueType` would work and in addition give more meaningfull output/information than before.

Which leads me to two questions:

1. Does anybody know what changed with reflection? What could be wrong? Previously i could also iterate over the properties of the Object.
2. Where can i inspect such changes? I don`t find anything about reflection in the offical documentation and there are no notes about reflection changes on the blog or anywhere else, can i browse the source somehow? (never tried)

Comment: Looks like a bug in the 1.2 beta—please [file a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

Comment: I cannot reproduce the crash in a compiled project, however it fails in a Playground.

Comment: I pasted it in Playground and had no issue.

Comment: Which XCode Version? Happens here in Version 6.3 (6D520o)

Answer (score 0):

Update: XCode 6.3 Beta 2 Swift 1.2: It was a bug and now it works.

It turns out this is a (confirmed) bug in Swift 1.2
I will post more information when i have it.